# URL Rewriting with case insensitivity

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to create URL case insensitive for which I am already using CheckSpelling On and it works fine.
In Parallel I also wished to remove extension from URL for that I applied

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It also worked.
But both doesn't work altogether.
If I keep both in htaccess it starts to give error 300 ("Multiple Choices")

Comment: What doesnt work? Can you post the uri that caused 300 error?

Comment: trying to make URL Case insensitive, URL is following http://dev-sql.digitreck.com/dev/Login
It will work if used as http://dev-sql.digitreck.com/dev/Login.php or http://dev-sql.digitreck.com/dev/login.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making it hard on yourself. It'd be easier if you do basic routing in your php. Just send anything to your `index.php` that's not a directory, and is either not a file or is a php file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (?>.*)(?<=\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php$). index.php [NS,L]
```

At the top of `index.php`, do something like this:

```
<?php

$url = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
$url = substr($url[0], 1);
if ($url) {
    $url = strtolower($url) . '.php';
    if (preg_match('@^[^./][^/]*(?:/[^./][^/]*)*$@', $url) && file_exists($url)) {
    .   # does not contain dotfiles, nor `..` directory traversal, so is a php file below web root
        include $url;
    }
    else {
        # virtual URL doesn't exist,
        # set 404 response code header and serve a default page
        include '404.php';
    }
    exit;
}

# no virtual URL, continue processing index.php
```

Add a `rel=canonical` to each page's `<head>`  that contains the lowercase URL (with any query string re-added) so you are not penalized for duplicate content,